# Correct usage of addtoStage when loading external swf

Tags: actionscript-3, stack-overflow

I am loading an external swf file into a parent swf file.

Previously, I was getting error 1009 and fixed that by using a listener event to add the swf to the stage before running any scripts.

The swf however fails to load completely when embedded into a parent swf as seen in this URL
http://viewer.zmags.com/publication/06b68a69?viewType=pubPreview#/06b68a69/1

Here is the code I am using.

Thank you for any input.

```
package 
{
    import com.greensock.TweenLite;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.SpreadMethod;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    public class slider5 extends Sprite
    {

        public var thumbPath:String = "Trailchair_thumb";
        public var featPath:String = "Trailchair";

        public var sliderIndex:Number = 1;
        public var currBg:Bitmap = new Bitmap();

        public var thumbCount:Number = 8;
        public var thumbHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public var thumbMask:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public var thumbX:Number = 0;
        public var thmPadding:Number = 10;
        public var thmWidth:Number;

        public var navLeft:Sprite = new Sprite();
        public var navRight:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000,0);
        public var sliderDir:String = "fwd";


        public function slider5()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        public function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void{
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            //THE BACKGROUND IMAGE
            currBg.alpha = 1;
            stage.addChildAt(currBg, 0);
            changeBg(sliderIndex);


            //The thumbMask a sprite with graphic rectangle
            thumbMask.x = 87;
            thumbMask.y = 572;
            thumbMask.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            thumbMask.graphics.drawRect(0,0, 406, 181);
            stage.addChildAt(thumbMask, 2);


            //The thumbSlider
            thumbHolder.x = 228;
            thumbHolder.y = 573;
            stage.addChildAt(thumbHolder, 1);
            thumbHolder.mask = thumbMask;

            buildThumbs();

            //add the nav
            navLeft.x = 100;
            navLeft.y = 609;

            navRight.x = 496;
            navRight.y = 609;

            stage.addChildAt(navLeft, 4);
            stage.addChildAt(navRight, 4);

            var navBmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
            navBmp.bitmapData = new navarrow(109,109);

            var navBmp_Rt:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
            navBmp_Rt.bitmapData = new navarrow(109,109);

            navLeft.addChild(navBmp);
            navLeft.scaleX *=  -1;

            navRight.addChild(navBmp_Rt);

            navLeft.useHandCursor = true;
            navLeft.buttonMode = true;
            navRight.useHandCursor = true;
            navRight.buttonMode = true;

            navLeft.name = "left";
            navRight.name = "right";

            navLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, navClick);
            navRight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, navClick);


            //add the active item frame
            var frame:Sprite = new Sprite();
            frame.x = 226;
            frame.y = 570;
            frame.graphics.lineStyle(10, 0x000000);
            frame.graphics.drawRect(0,0,131, 181);

            stage.addChildAt(frame, 6);

            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeEvt);
            timer.start();

        }


        public function changeBg(index):void
        {
            //set the first slide from our library and add to the stage
            var currBg_Class:Class = getDefinitionByName( featPath + index ) as Class;
            currBg.bitmapData = new currBg_Class(597,842);

            //fade it in
            TweenLite.from(currBg, 0.5, {alpha:0});
        }

        public function buildThumbs():void
        {
            var currThm:Class;

            for (var i:uint = 1; i<=thumbCount; i++)
            {
                currThm = getDefinitionByName( thumbPath + i ) as Class;
                var thmBmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
                thmBmp.bitmapData = new currThm(126,176);
                thmBmp.x = thumbX;
                thumbHolder.addChild(thmBmp);

                thumbX +=  thmBmp.width + thmPadding;
            }

            thmWidth = thmBmp.width + thmPadding;
        }


        public function navClick(e):void
        {

            timer.reset();
            timer.start();
            var dir:String = e.currentTarget.name;

            if (dir=="left" && thumbHolder.x < 228 )
            {
                sliderIndex--;
                TweenLite.to(thumbHolder, 0.5, {x:thumbHolder.x + thmWidth});
                //thumbHolder.x = thumbHolder.x + thmWidth;
            }
            else if (dir=="right" && thumbHolder.x > - 724 )
            {
                sliderIndex++;
                TweenLite.to(thumbHolder, 0.5, {x:thumbHolder.x - thmWidth});
                //thumbHolder.x = thumbHolder.x - thmWidth;
            }

            if (sliderIndex == thumbCount)
            {
                sliderDir = "bk";
            }

            if (sliderIndex == 1)
            {
                sliderDir = "fwd";
            }

            changeBg(sliderIndex);
        }


        public function timeEvt(e):void
        {
            if (sliderDir == "fwd")
            {
                navRight.dispatchEvent(new Event(MouseEvent.CLICK));
            }
            else if (sliderDir == "bk")
            {
                navLeft.dispatchEvent(new Event(MouseEvent.CLICK));
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Are you using Flash IDE (eg: flash CS 5)? When you say "embedded" do you mean the SWF is in the Library? or using something like: [Embed(source="MySWFfile.swf")]? Anyhow your changeBG function has a problem. You can't get bitmapData from a Class only displayObjects (MClip, Sprite). You could try adding "var current_Bg_img:MovieClip = new currBg_Class();" before going for the bitmapData "currBg.bitmapData.draw (current_Bg_img);" This is from memory so let me know if you have problems. (continued..)

Comment: (cont..) I suggest not to load SWFs as classes and try load the SWF slides same as you would load images. See this tutorial (.jpg can be replaced with .swf).. http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/ Good luck.

Comment: @VC.One, Thank you for your reply. I am using Flash CS6 and the compiled swf is being loaded into a parent flash player which I have no control over.

The swf runs fine on its own without any errors whatsoever, I always debug my flash files. However the moment I get the swf loaded into the parent swf, I get the runtime 1009 error stating that the function slider5() is where the error is located.

I have added your suggesting but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need it you can try these two suggestions. Note I didnt know about Zmags and initially assumed that it was your own domain name. That's why I suggested you use the Loader class. It worked for me when I did a test version of a parent.swf' that loaded a test 'child.swf' containing your code. It actually loaded the child swf without problems.

1. Change from extending Sprite to extending MovieClip
2. Avoid checking for added to stage in this project

Explanations:

1. Extending MovieClip instead of Sprite

I Long story short Flash wont like your swf extending Sprite then being opened by a parent loader that extends Movieclip. The ZMag player will be extending MovieClip. It's logical and the docs do confirm this in a way. Whether it fixes your issue or not just keep it MovieClip when using ZMags.

1. Avoiding Stage referencing in your code..

Looking at this Zmags Q&A documentaion:

http://community.zmags.com/articles/Knowledgebase/Common-questions-on-flash-integration

Looking at Question 4.. In their answer these two stand out.

- Reference of the stage parameter in the uploaded SWF conflicting with the publication
- Badly or locally referenced resources in the SWF you uploaded which cannot be found

Is it really necessary to have an added_to_stage check in this? If it wont hurt then I suggest dropping the stage_added checking from function slider5() and instead cut/paste in there the code you have from the function onAddedToStage(e:Event).

Hope it helps.